# flex-wrap wraps whole string

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple items in a container. Which I want to wrap.

[image: when wraps]

But what I really want to do is part of the second label to fit in the first line (as much as the available space) and the rest follows in the second line. What am I missing?

Desired:

[image: desired]

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='content'>Label1 |</div>
  <div class='content'>Loooooooong long label</div>
</div>
```

NOTE: The parent needs to be `display: flex` as the code above is a simplified version of the actual code. Thanks.

Comment: flexbox CSS is intended for distributing child elements as rectangles in rows and columns. You cannot use `flex` if you have a requirement where a child element needs itself to break partly into a next row.

Comment: Yeah, that's the kind of my point of asking here as I mentioned above NOTE: The parent needs to be display: flex as the code above is a simplified version of the actual code.

Comment: So the answer then is: no, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t achieve that inside a container styled as `display: flex`. But even if you can’t change the CSS on the `.container` to remove `display: flex`, you may be able to override it with a `display: block` style rule later in your document. Remember that later style rules override earlier ones.

The final pieces of the puzzle are then to style your `.content` with `display: inline` and `word-break: break-all` to make the two labels follow on from each other and break wherever a line is filled.

```css
/* ..... maybe you can’t change this ..... */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 4px;
}

/* ..... but maybe you can add this further down in your html ..... */

.container {
  display: block; /* overrides display:flex from above */
  width: 125px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content {
  display: inline;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
 <div class='content'>Label1 |</div>
 <div class='content'>Loooooooong long label</div>
</div>
```